# ¿Cómo bloquear el acceso a un archivo desde un servidor Tomcat?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, java-ee, tomcat

Muy buenas tardes compañeros , tengo un dolor de cabeza con este tema. Bueno he podido bloquear el acceso directo a las imagenes que estan dentro de la carpeta images como muestro en la siguiente imagen.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como vemos en esta captura de pantalla, al acceder directamente a dicha URL bloquea el acceso lanzando un error 403-Forbiden, hasta ahi todo bien.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al momento de ingresar en mi jsp al querer mostrar dicha imagen con la etiqueta img de HTML5 ya no se muestra como antes.

```
<img src="images/1.jpg">
```

Como puedo solucionar esto ya que mi objetivo es bloquear el acceso directo por URL a mis imagenes , pero quiero mostrarlos en mi JSP cuando es procesado y enviado al cliente como HTML. Quiero que el cliente no vea mis imagenes directamente, utilizo el servidor TOMCAT.Muchas gracias por su atencion.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Por favor, no muestres el código como capturas de pantalla; introdúcelo en la pregunta como texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo habitual en estos casos es ofrecer el recurso mediante servlet:

1. Creas un servlet llamado ServletDownload
2. En el get(), compruebas si el usuario ha iniciado sesión, permisos, etc...
3. Luego cargas en memoria el fichero que te han solicitado, buscándolo en la carpeta privada, que es visible solo desde el servidor.
4. La devuelves al usuario como respuesta (quizá hay que tocar algo del MIME).

Ejemplo básico: https://www.baeldung.com/servlet-download-file

Comment: Perdona por la demora, pero tu comentario me sirvio muchas gracias amigo.

Answer (score -1):

Sitúa las carpetas dentro de `WEB-INF`, de esta forma serán accesibles por tu aplicación  pero no desde el exterior.
Quita las restricciones de seguridad del `web.xml`, son innecesarias si las imágenes se colocan dentro de `WEB-INF`.

Por ejemplo, dada una carpeta imagenes dentro de `WEB-INF`:

```
<img src = "<%= application.getRealPath("/imagenes/1.jpg") %>">
```

Comment: ¿? Pero el `<img src/>` se ejecuta desde el exterior (el navegador web). Y las restricciones de seguridad que ponga el OP en el `web.xml` no deberían haber cambiado para nada el path a las imágenes (supongo, porque no miro código que esté como captura de pantalla).

Comment: El caso es que aplicar restricciones de seguridad para un caso de uso que ya controla el tomcat me parece innecesario.

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias por su respuesta en verdad colocar las carpetas imágenes en el WEB-INF funciona a la perfección. Gracias me ayudaste bastante.

Comment: No me llego ,uno vez que es procesado el jsp al cliente le llega la ruta asi.  La imagen no se llega a mostrar por favor ayudarme.                                                                                                 <img class="img-fluid" alt="Image" src="C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\wtpwebapps\PlantillaSocial\WEB-INF\fotos\4.jpg">

Comment: ¿Está la imagen en esa ruta?

Comment: Si esta en ese ruta , por favor ayudame , cuando aplico  application.getRealPath() .. Pareciera como si tuviera acceso a dicho archivo.